# Distribute an iOS framework with 3rd party libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, carthage

I'm currently developing a custom framework that makes use of different dependencies such as Moya, RxSwift, ObjectMapper etc. The only issue is that whilst developing the framework I set the search path to the Carthage folder so it knows where the files are when I'm developing the framework.

So the issue is when it comes to distribution because there are so many 3rd parties getting the user to download frameworks and/or link them themselves seems like a long task and I'm unable to distribute the framework via Carthage or CocoaPods.

So I'm currently looking for advice/guidance on how to distribute my own framework and embed these third parties within it whilst still being able to prevent duplicate symbols if the user includes the library within their project i.e. My framework uses RxMoya and the user adds RxMoya as a dependency within the project via Carthage, CocoaPods or manually.